# how to create nav-tabs next botton validation in jquery i have to validate specific field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to js I have simplest code specific field validation in nav-tabs next button for implement.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"><li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>`<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li></ul>
<div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNext">Next</a></div><div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNext">Next</a><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrevious">Previous</a></div><div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnPrevious">Previous</a></div></div>


<script>
      $('#btnNext').click(function(){$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });$('#btnPrevious').click(function(){$('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes here.  Div tab-pane 3 should have id='tab3' instead of tab2.  Also elements must have unique ids.  So the previous and next buttons cannot have same ids.  Instead of id, use class to navigate via buttons using jquery like this -

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>    
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"><a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a><a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a></div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"><a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</a></div>
        </div>
    <script>
      $('.btnNext').click(function(){$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });$('.btnPrevious').click(function(){$('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks, t-shah  my main problem I have to create specific field validation  like tab1 4 fields I have to validate 2 fields before next